# When importing a file that has classes, do class attributes get initialized?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python, so please bear with me.
I read somewhere that when you import a file, it's exactly as if you executed that file. This confused me because I started wondering whether class attributes also get initialized when importing.

Let me give you an example,
Say we have this file named cat.py:

```
#cat.py
class RawFeature:
    bat = 5
```

And we have another file here:

```
import cat as c

#Does 'bat' get initialized upon calling?  
print(c.RawFeature.bat)
```

Does 'bat' get initialized upon calling or when the 'cat.py' file is imported?

If it gets initialized upon importing this really changes the flow of the script because let's say the class variable 'bat' is initialized by calling some function...

Comment: just add a print statement inside class for debugging

Comment: Yes, all the module-level code including `class` definitions will get executed the first time the module is imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RawFeature.bat` will be initialized as soon as you import the module `cat` or anything from the module like `RawFeature`. As a quick litmus test, if you store the following in a file called `thing.py`,

```
def initialize():
    print('Calling initialize')
    return 5


class Thing:
    class_attr = initialize()
```

then try to import `thing` or `Thing` in a Python REPL shell, you'll noticed that `Calling initialize` gets printed before making any further calls.

Answer (score 1):

**@rajith-thennakoon -**

> Adding to kingkupps reponse, If you want your class/methods/anyCodeSnippet to restrict from
> getting initialized while being imported, you can add the
> class/methods/anyCodeSnippet in the if block as mentioned below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def initialize():
        print('Calling initialize')
        return 5
    class Thing:
        class_attr = initialize()
```